# Make SciChart TextAnnotation Honor its given X2 value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scichart

Is there a way to make the TextAnnotation honor its X2 value? I want to start a TextAnnotation at a certain datetime and span to another. I would use the box annotation but I need it to contain text and be dynamically generated.

Answer (score 0):

in SciChart WPF, the [TextAnnotation](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/win/current/The%20TextAnnotation%20Type.html) only responds to X1,X2 values.

You can set the alignment of the TextAnnotation using the HorizontalAnchorPoint / VerticalAnchorPoint properties.

[image]

You can set the Width/Height of the TextAnnotation.

If you wanted to display text inside a box region (X1,X2,Y1,Y2) then consider [templating the BoxAnnotation](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/win/current/The%20CustomAnnotation%20Type.html).

```
<s:SciChartSurface.Annotations>
   <s:BoxAnnotation X1="2" X2="8" Y1="2" Y2="8" Background="#33FFFFFF"
                    BorderBrush="#55FFFFFF" BorderThickness="3" Padding="5">
      <s:BoxAnnotation.Template>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="s:BoxAnnotation">
            <Border x:Name="PART_BoxAnnotationRoot"
               Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}"
               Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
               BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
               BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
               CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}">
               <Viewbox Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                  <TextBlock Text="Hello CustomAnnotation World!"></TextBlock>
               </Viewbox>
            </Border>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </s:BoxAnnotation.Template>
   </s:BoxAnnotation>
</s:SciChartSurface.Annotations>
```

[image]